# Floating a left-aligned horizontal menu in middle

Tags: css, html

I am having difficulty in getting a menu list to float in the center of it's parent container.  Here is the address of the page: [simplekitchenandbath.com/staging/](http://simplekitchenandbath.com/staging/)
And the necessary code snippets:

```
    div#wrapper {
        width:1100px;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0 0 50px 0;
    }

       div#content-main {
            background-color:#000;
            width:1024px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }

            nav {
                background-color:#000;
                height:30px;
            }

                div#nav-container {
                width:720px;
                margin:0 auto;
            }

ul#nav                         { position:relative; }
ul#nav li                      { float: left; zoom: 1; list-style-type:none; margin:0; border-bottom:1px solid #FFF; }
ul#nav a:hover                 { color:#DDD; text-decoration:none; }
ul#nav a:active                { color:#DDD; }
ul#nav li a                    { display:block; padding:0 10px 0 0; color:#FFF; text-transform:uppercase; }
ul#nav li:last-child a          { padding-right:0; }
ul#nav li.hover, ul#nav li:hover  { position: relative; }
```

Comment: The expression "float in the center" makes little sense. You either float left or right.

Comment: margin:0 auto; allows for floating in the center of any container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div#nav-container {
  width:575px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

the width is too big on #nav-container. set it to 575px !

Answer (score 1):

Make the width smaller and to align it in the center place it inside the container of the element and set its margin to 0 auto; try responsive webdesign with css3 media queries and targeting two different monitor size... because the site on 780px monitor it has the slider to  go horizontally.... so basically:

```
<div class="container">
    ... some code ...
</div>

css:
.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Thanks for reading... Love to hear some response on my answer.

Comment: You were right about having to reduce the container size, but you hadn't specified which one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` on the `#nav` element, and `text-align:center` on the `#nav-container`